# The ggplotly() causes error object 'tickvals' not found

Tags: r, plotly, ggplotly

I use the code below to create an activity frequency plot but when I include it in `ggplotly(`) I get `object 'tickvals' not found`

```
library(bupaR)
library(eventdataR)
library(plotly)

sip<-bupaR::simple_eventlog(eventlog = eventdataR::sepsis,
                case_id = "case_id",
                activity_id = "activity",
                #activity_instance_id = "activity_instance_id",
                timestamp = "timestamp",
                #lifecycle_id = "lifecycle",
                resource_id = "resource"
                )

sip %>% activity_frequency(level="trace") %>% plot()
ggplotly( sip %>% activity_frequency(level="trace") %>% plot()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(bupaR)
library(eventdataR)
library(plotly)
library(edeaR)

#to avoid the axis overlapping
layout_ggplotly <- function(gg, x = -0.02, y = -0.08){
    gg[['x']][['layout']][['annotations']][[1]][['y']] <- x
    gg[['x']][['layout']][['annotations']][[2]][['x']] <- y
    gg
}

#making a plot
sip <- simple_eventlog(sepsis,
                       case_id = "case_id",
                       activity_id = "activity",
                       timestamp = "timestamp",
                       resource_id = "resource"
)

k <- sip %>% 
     activity_frequency(level="trace") %>%
     plot()

graph <- ggplotly(k) %>%
         layout_ggplotly

graph
```

**Output:**

[image]